# Autocomplete suggestions after dot in python using company-mode

Tags: python, company-mode

[Jedi](https://tkf.github.io/emacs-jedi/latest/) has support for auto-completion after dot

`(setq jedi:complete-on-dot t)`

=> Main goal is to [Finding what methods a Python object has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34439/finding-what-methods-a-python-object-has)

---

**[Q]** Does `company-mode` has the same support (`complete-on-dot`)? Basically after the dot I want it to detect only the object's functions or variables for completion suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: not being a python programmer I hadn't actually looked up Jedi. Jedi is an emacs extension. Why not just use that?  It IS integrated with company mode.

See here: [Python Programming in Emacs](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~chaoliu/2017/09/01/python-programming-in-emacs/)

```elisp
(defun company-jedi-setup ()
  (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-jedi))
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'company-jedi-setup)
```

and

```elisp
(setq jedi:setup-keys t)
(setq jedi:complete-on-dot t)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:setup)
```

===== below left for reference

You can bind "." to company-complete as described [here](http://company-mode.github.io/)

Something like

```elisp
(defun dot-pressed()
  (interactive)
  (insert ".")
  (call-interactively 'company-complete))

(define-key python-mode-map (kbd ".") #'dot-pressed)
```

but that would be pretty intrusive. I force completion with C-tab:-

```elisp
(use-package 
  company 
  :diminish company-mode 
  :config
  (use-package  
    company-box 

    :disabled 
    :diminish company-box-mode 
    :hook (company-mode . company-box-mode)) 
  (require 'company-ispell)
  (global-company-mode) 
  :bind ("C-<tab>" . company-complete))
```

That said I strongly recommend you have a look as [lsp](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode), this will give you live language-specific completion based on a background language server which parses your code and libraries and gives proper context-specific completion and navigation. It comes with its own "company-lsp" completion candidate for company.

Python and it's requirements are documented on that page linked above,

Comment: I added your suggestions but when I type `self` and press dot, I cannot type dot

Comment: Yeah, as I said its intrusive and you need to code around that, hence my suggestion to use C-tab or even tab which is wired in to do the right things with tab/complete and yasnippet. Seriously think about lsp. You might think to have a look at the documentation for tab-always-indent.

Comment: incidentally, I updated the bind code above. But I'm sure someone more au-fait will provide a more robust technique.

Comment: Hm after having `self.` all combinations show up, is it the normal case?

Comment: See edit above. Jedi IS integrated with company mode.

Comment: I was recommended to use `company-mode` for some reason that's why I never checked jedi

Comment: But when I applied your answer, `company-mode` is disabled

Comment: Possibly you're confused - it can be confusing when starting out. Jedi mode integrates to company-mode. In other words - the config I showed and linked to above allows Jedi to use company-mode for completion. Jedi provides a company-backend. I am not providing you a working jedi configuration - this is available at the link above and in the jedi docs.

Comment: `company`'s coloring is also gone where i want to keep it on using `jedi`

Comment: I think I should use `company-jedi` (https://github.com/syohex/emacs-company-jedi) instead of `jedi` // https://github.com/syohex/emacs-company-jedi says: `Please do not install jedi package for company users, it is an auto-complete plugin of jedi`